# How to find the most similar word in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of words

```
list = ['car', 'animal', 'house', 'animation']
```

and I want to compare every list item with a string `str1` and the output should be the most similar word. Example: If `str1` would be `anlmal` then `animal` is the most similar word. How can I do this in python? Usually the words I have in my list are good distinguishable from each other.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches):

```
difflib.get_close_matches(word, ['car', 'animal', 'house', 'animation'])
```

As you can see from perusing [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/de4ffe244440/Lib/difflib.py#l701), the "close" matches are sorted from best to worst.

```
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('anlmal', ['car', 'animal', 'house', 'animation'])
['animal']
```

Comment: Is this time consuming if I have a big list? Or this function has any speed optimization?

Answer (score 3):

I checked difflib.get_close_matches(), but it didn't work for me correctly. I write here a robust solution, use as:

closest_match, closest_match_idx = find_closet_match(test_str, list2check)

```
def find_closet_match(test_str, list2check):
scores = {}
for ii in list2check:
    cnt = 0
    if len(test_str)<=len(ii):
        str1, str2 = test_str, ii
    else:
        str1, str2 = ii, test_str
    for jj in range(len(str1)):
        cnt += 1 if str1[jj]==str2[jj] else 0
    scores[ii] = cnt
scores_values        = numpy.array(list(scores.values()))
closest_match_idx    = numpy.argsort(scores_values, axis=0, kind='quicksort')[-1]
closest_match        = numpy.array(list(scores.keys()))[closest_match_idx]
return closest_match, closest_match_idx
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible to return not only the closest but maybe top n, maybe top 5?

Comment: I know that is possible

Comment: Well @JorgeA.Salazar, a simple solution for now would be just run the function n times and the remove the closest_match from the list2check after each iteration. One can also try to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

to answer this"do you know if it is possible to return not only the closest but maybe top n, maybe top 5?" by @jorge A. Salazar

```
def find_closest_matches(test_str, list2check, top_n=10):
    scores = {}
    for ii in list2check:
        cnt = 0
        min_len = min(len(test_str), len(ii))
        for jj in range(min_len):
            cnt += 1 if test_str[jj] == ii[jj] else 0
        scores[ii] = cnt
    sorted_scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:top_n]
    closest_matches = [item[0] for item in sorted_scores]
    return closest_matches
```

Comment: It would be helpful to re-write this comment to include what your answer does, so that new viewers don't have to find Jorge's comment to understand the relevance.